# Cypress Tests Fail Sporadically

Tags: angular, gitlab, cypress

We have been debugging failing cypress tests for a few days now and cannot seem to narrow down the cause. The tests run in our GitLab CICD pipeline.

Error we see in the logs:

> Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to
> object\nTypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object\n    at
> Function.keys ()\n    at MapSubscriber.project
> (http://localhost:49152/main.2e49092b1a3db7b9c078.js:8506:28)\n    at
> MapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/map.js.MapSubscriber._next
> ...

We added a cypress plugin to rerun the any test if they fail and it always passes the second time. It is not the same test that fails each time, it varies. The failure seems to happen because a page fails to render due to the error above but it is unclear what that error is from.

We have noticed the tests pass in Firefox so we are only seeing this error in headless chrome/chromium based browsers.

Any ideas what we could look at to find out what's going wrong?

Comment: Sounds like a timing issue, as well as a possible miss on an undefined parm. Step 1) don't do anything on those tests until a validation check is made on input parms. Step 2) Use Cypress' own wait routines to ensure the content is there.   I've written a 14 part series on Cypress that may help https://dev.to/jwp/angular-and-cypress-in-20-minutes-21be

Comment: I also thought it might be a race condition but it turned out to be a memory issue with Chrome on Docker. See answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We were able to get a more helpful error after adding a logging package to Cypress for our front end.

> error (network): Failed to load resource: net::ERR_INSUFFICIENT_RESOURCES

Our issue turns out to be an open issue with Cypress where Chrome is eating up too much memory and crashing Docker.

Issue and resolution are posted here: https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/7457

> Follow https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/continuous-integration.html#In-Docker and then setting --ipc=host on our docker containers [will] stop the issue.

Answer (score 0):

After digging a little, adding `--disable-dev-shm-usage` flag to chrome solve the issue for me. You can use `--ipc=host` but the isolation is better without it.

I encountered the same issue with Karma and Chrome >= 90 in Docker.